# WordPress add author name in permalink - slug problem

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I created 3 custom post types (`dissertation`, `subject-imposed`, `subject-free`) for a project with students.

I would like to add for each student his name in the permalink :
http://www.example.com/custom-post-type-name/name-of-the-student/title-of-post

Example :
http://www.example.com/dissertation/mickael-fox/my-presentation

```
$post_types_name = array('subject-imposed', 'subject-free', 'dissertation');

function ccn_author_in_permalink($post_link, $post) {
    global $post_types_name;

    foreach ($post_types_name as $post_type_name) {
        if ( $post_type_name != get_post_type($post) ) {
            $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
            $author_name = $authordata->display_name;
            $author_name_final = sanitize_title($author_name);

            $post_link = str_replace('%author%', $author_name_final, $post_link);
        }

        return $post_link;
    }
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'ccn_author_in_permalink', 10, 4);

//  Réecriture
function ccn_rewrite_url() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%author%','([^&]+)' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'ccn_rewrite_url' );
```

In the settings of `Custom Post Type Maker` plugin I do this
[image]

All work fine for two custom post types : `dissertation` and `subject-free` but with `subject-imposed` I got `%author%` in this permalink : http://www.example.com/custom-post-type-name/%author%/title-of-post

What's wrong ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the code you show is working for 2 of the 3 CPTs then its most likely the problem isn't there. It's more likely to be in the Custom Post Type Maker. Could it be a typo? You have called the CPT `subject-imposed` in the code but the Custom Rewrite Slug is `sujet-impose`

Comment: Yeah I renamed the slug in french. Do you think the problem is here?

Comment: Did you do the same thing for the other 2 CPTs? If they work and this one doesn't, this one is different in some way.

Comment: I changed the slug name for the two CPT who work : memoire for dissertation and sujet libre for subject-free

Comment: Without being able to see your setup and the rest of the code, the only thing I can suggest is to compare the 3 CPTs to try to find what is different about the one that doesn't work. The only other thing I can think of is would you have something else with the same slug (e.g. a page or post)? If you had anything that used this slug before, clear your bin, your cache, permalinks etc in case the problem is something do with the old slug.